# Logstash to Opensearch , _dateparsefailure tag

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, opensearch

I have some problems while using logstash to opensearch.

```
filter{
    grok {
            patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"]
            match => [ "message","%{DATE_FORM:logdate}%{LOGTYPE:logtype}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}" ]
    }
    date {
            match => ["logdate", "yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss:SSS"]
            timezone => "UTC"
            target=>"timestamp"
    }

    mutate {
            remove_field => ["message"]
            add_field => {
                    "file" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}"
            }
    }
}
```

This is the conf file I'm using for logstash.
In the opensearch console

```
@timestamp : Dec 15, 2022 @ 18:10:56.975
logdate [2022.12.10-11.57.36:345]
tags _dateparsefailure
```

The timestamp , logdate are different and _dateparsefailure error occurs.

In the raw logs , it starts with

```
[2022.12.10-11.57.36:345]
```

this format.

Right now ,

```
logdate : raw log's timestamp
@timestamp : the time that log send to opensearch
```

I want to match logdate and @timestamp.
How can I modify the filter.date.match part to make the results of the logdate and @timestamp filters the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple times you can have more than one `filter.date.match`, you can do this:

```
filter{
    date {
            match => ["logdate", "yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss:SSS"]
            timezone => "UTC"
            target=>"logdate"
    }
    date {
            match => ["@timestamp", "yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss:SSS"]
            timezone => "UTC"
            target=>"@timestamp"
    }
}
```

If your time field has multiple formats, you can do this:

```
date {
  match => [ "logdate", "yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss:SSS", "third_format", "ISO8601" ]
  target=> "@timestamp"
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match